# sqlalchemy compile error:can't generate DDL for NullType()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'person', column 'id'): Can't generate DDL for NullType(); did you forget to specify a type on this Column?
```

I use SQLite but cannot make a table

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///one.db'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    pets = db.relationship('Pet',backref='owner')

class Pet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

Comment: Any updates? Facing same issue on "uuid = Column("uuid", as_uuid=True)" as column name

Comment: The error message is consistent with having `id = db.Column(primary_key=True)` in one of the classes, so the code in the question does not reproduce the behaviour.